# Is there any option to calculate mean curvature and specific surface area in Dragonfly software

Tags: parameters, image-segmentation, analysis, python-dragonfly

For an image data how can I calculate the mean curvature(mm2) and specific surface area(mm) values after the image segmentation using Otsu thresholding in Dragonfly software.

After image segmentation I was able to calculate Euler characteristics, volume density but I was not able to calculate Mean curvature and Specific surface area.